# Relation of eigen values of a given matrix with its sub-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How are the number of positive,negative and zero eigen values of this matrix :

> $A=$\begin{bmatrix} B  & c\\c^T &d\end{bmatrix}

related with that of $B$ where $c$ is a $n\times 1$ vector?

Here $B$ is  a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $Bu=0$ and $c^Tu\neq 0$ for some $u$.

Since $Bu=0\implies B$ is singular.

How should I proceed with the given information?

Please give some hints but not the complete solution.

Comment: I don't think this is going anywhere. This kind of stuffs are usually best viewed from the perspective of Courant-Fischer minimax principle or the interlacing inequality.

Comment: How should I proceed then here?@user1551

Answer (score 1):

By [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), you may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{I_r&&&0\\ &-I_s&&0\\ &&0&v\\ 0&0&v^T&a},
$$
where $r+s\le n-1$, $v\in\mathbb R^{n-1-(r+s)}$ and $a$ is a (possibly zero) scalar.

Alternatively, you may apply the powerful [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Will you please kindly explain how is this obtained in Sylvester's Law of Inertia??

Comment: @Mathematics First, apply Sylvester's law of inertia directly to $B$. This turns $B$ into $I_r\oplus I_s\oplus0$, where the zero diagonal block is a square matrix of size $n-1-r-s$. Then use matrix congruence to kill off the first $r+s$ entries on the last row or last column of $A$.